# Losing elements' positions with css

Tags: html, css

I need to do smth like this:
[image]

Left box should have static width and right one resizes to full browser width. 
Height of the boxes also should be resizeable.

P.S.
Sorry guys, it took a while to make fiddle work.

[So it is here](http://jsfiddle.net/QggCv/1/)

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="leftPage">
        </div>
        <div class="rightPage">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is:

I have silver left page. I want it to have static width. Lets say 454px.
And I want right page (black one) to be dynamically resized to screen.

Variant with width 20%/80% is not good for me.
Is it possible with CSS only?
I got good answers with jquery/js but still interesting if it can be done with CSS only)

Sorry for troubles)

Comment: show us HTML code as well. jsfiddle link would be great

Comment: you can set width: 20%; min-width: 200px; for left side and set 80% for right side. give it a try

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want leftPage and rightPage to be beside each-other where leftPage has a static width and rightPage has the width of whatever is left.  OR  . Do you want that leftPage has a static width and rightPage has 100% width and is beneath leftPage?

Comment: Look at my answer. I have suggested 4 different options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript/jQuery**

If you want left column to be static and the right column to be dynamic, you will need Javascript or a CSS preprocessor like SASS. That's the only real solution that is supported by older browsers.

```
// parent width - leftpage width = remainings
$('div.rightPage').width(
    $('div.rightPage').parent().width() - $('div.leftPage').width()
);
```

**Fluid layout**

If you really want a pure-CSS solution, I suggest to use a fluid layout instead. This is cross-browser as well.

```
div.leftPage { width: 25%; }
div.rightPage { width: 75%; }
```

**Simulated table**

As alternative, you can still simulate a table layout using `display: table`. Tables do have that functionality. [Check out the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QHyjT/) (resize the window to see it working)

This may not work in IE6 and IE7.

**Native table**

In the end, if you are OK with tables, you can use native tables, which are cross-browser ;)

CSS

```
table td.fixed { width: 200px; }
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="fixed">
                <p>Left content</p>
            </td><td>
                <p>Right content</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Finally, in order to resize it vertically, you need to set `resize: vertical`.

```
div.leftpage, div.rightpage { resize: vertical; }
```

Comment: Oh man, that's awesome) So many ways to do it in your comments) Thanks a lot!

Comment: On the fluid layout CSS solution; be cautious of padding these directly on parallel elements as they may get askew.

Comment: I would like to add that some browsers already have an early implementation of flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Answer (score 1):

Using table is much easier.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
    </div>
    <table class="content-wrapper">
      <tr>
        <td class="leftPage">LEFT</td>
        <td class="rightPage">RIGHT</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
table
{
  width:100%;
}
.leftPage
{
width: 454px;
}
```

Unless you really want to stick with DIVs?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `absolute` position at a `relative` container and have your `right` `div` position at `left` the same amount of pixels as your `left` width. Like below:

```
div.content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
div.leftPage {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 454px;
    position:absolute;
}
div.rightPage {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:454px;
}
```

Also its good to set the `body` height at 100% if you want your `div`s to expand across the page:

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

And here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XLLSA/1/

**EDIT**

I fixed the search div: http://jsfiddle.net/XLLSA/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
div.left { 
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
}
div.right { 
    width: 80%; 
}
```

Comment: Tested this in chrome, didn't work. I was hoping it would because it is pretty elegant :( Also, min/max-width/height doesn't quite work in older browsers.

Comment: It's not good because of min width. If screen is narrow it will be to wide